# apt install libleptonica-dev fails

Tags: ubuntu, apt, leptonica

Im trying to use Tesseract-OCR for in a program and am having issues installing. Following the instructions on [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling#linux)

When I try the command

`sudo apt-get install libleptonica-dev`

I get

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tesseract$ sudo apt install libleptonica-dev
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package libleptonica-dev

Does it no longer exist or is it under a different name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you updated your package cache with `sudo apt update`?

Also, look into https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1025.